# Get value from input type file

Tags: javascript, php, file, text, input

I would like to change the input type text value when I use the input type file. I've tried the following code, but I still cant figure it out how to handle this problem.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="imagem" class="filename" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_dados['imagem'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" readonly />

<input type="file" name="id_imagem">
```

JS:

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function (event, files, label) {
var file_name = this.value.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '')
$('input[type="text"].filename').value(file_name);
});
```

Comment: which value you want to set in text?

Comment: i correct a few bugs on the code, but still not working. What i would like to do is geting the value from input file and make it showing at input text, the value the input text is geting is from database mysql

Comment: You can't, the value is read-only. Also reading the value of `type="file"` is limited. You'll get a "fakepath/filename.ext" only.

Comment: already removed that part of code readonly but the value from input file still not showing at input text

Comment: Check this file_name value in alert..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful,jquery uses "val()" method to access to input values.

I guess you have some error in console with you script..

Try with

```
$('input[type="file"].filename').val(file_name);
```

In same way, better get file value with following code:

```
var file_name = $(this).val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'r trying to change the **text** field value, why are you targeting the **file** value?

The code would looks like:

```
/* Let's bind it just for the id_imagem, not the all input[type="file"] */
$('#id_imagem').bind
(
    'change',
    function(e)
    {
        /* Supposing your fields are inside a <form>, this notation will work */
        this.form.elements['imagem'].value = this.value.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
        return true;
    }
);
```